# how to use libPhoneNumber-iOS for formats phone numbers on-the-fly when users enter each digit

Tags: java, iphone, ios, phone-number, libphonenumber

libPhoneNumber has function AsYouTypeFormatter (formats phone numbers on-the-fly when users enter each digit). Work example:

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
AsYouTypeFormatter formatter = phoneUtil.getAsYouTypeFormatter("US");
System.out.println(formatter.inputDigit('6'));  // Outputs "6"
...  // Input more digits
System.out.println(formatter.inputDigit('3'));  // Now outputs "650 253"
```

How can I do it with libPhoneNumber-iOS ? It's really? 
I didn't find similar function.

Thanks!

Comment: This is tagged as `iphone` and `ios` yet you are asking about Java code.

Comment: This had tag "libphonenumber" also.
I try to prioritize different for tags.